# What are the benefits and drawbacks of the HTML5 Keygen element?

Tags: encryption, certificates, html, web-browser, html-5

As of January 2013, what are the potential benefits and drawbacks of the HTML5 Keygen element?

Answer (score 12):

**Pros**

- It can [improve security when authenticating](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_elements.asp) (in addition to a multi-factor device)
- If used as a "client certificate", it can make MITM attacks much more difficult
- The Keygen tag is implemented across most non-IE browsers, making it very easy to implement
- Works regardless of administrator permission.  With IE Active X controls can be disabled and IE and browser settings can make key generation impossible on tightly controlled systems.   In this situation the current Keygen in non-IE browsers is often the only error free method to generate and use Client certificates

**Cons & Deficiencies**

- Certificates are not easily portable between systems  (to some, this is a "pro")
- The private key is not stored in a standard location
- The UI is [confusing and difficult to understand](http://www.w3.org/wiki/Foaf+ssl/Clients/CertSelection)
- Requires the user to select the appropriate key length from a list. Most users are not equipped to make this decision.
- Poor user experience when the user is prompted to download the certificate.  A better approach would have the key submission and certificate response integrated into the same control.  ([possible solution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_crypto) also this [*on S.O.*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8547503/328397) )
- `<keygen>` does not provide a mechanism for managing certificate expiry
- No standard key length or hash implemented across browsers
- Algorithm support is missing (RSA, DSA, ECC, etc)
- Keysize selection should come from the form, not user selectable.
- The signature is based on MD5 ([which can be mitigated by a time based challenge](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=13518))
- Non-Exportable keygen flag is missing
- Hardware protected keygen flag is missing
- Password protection required is missing
- The certificate is limited to RSA based applications
- The HTML form could be modified locally and [key generation security reduced accordingly](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2009Sep/0931.html)
- If enrolling to a Microsoft Certificate Server, [the only supported CertType is "server"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc249713.aspx)
  via [DCOM API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374863.aspx)
- The format used by  is not standard and only provides a subset of already established protocols like [PKCS10](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986) , [CMC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5272) , and [CRMF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4211) . This prevents  from supporting non-RSA based certificates, extensions for additional client information, and key escrow
- Not supported in IE due to better support with `CertEnroll` [and the issues described here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2009Sep/0043.html)

Comment: do you know of a way to ensure or see that a generated private key doesn't leave my machine in such a process?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Right now, the most interesting way to deploy certificates may be based on Microsoft CS, IF the web service enrollment can be used on multiple platforms... http://security.stackexchange.com/q/82657/396